# Avoiding TempData MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have read most of the Q&A's on SO and they all seem to use TempData as the answer for the question of redirecting to actions with messages like "form saved/thanks for doing whatever".

I am aware that you can use cookies and sessions to do this.  The issue is I want to avoid sessions and therefore TempData as underneath it just uses sessions.

So, question - How can you avoid duplicate inserts and send various messages to other actions without relying on Session/Cookies/Querystrings and to add to the mix hidden fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)Only way to avoid duplicates would be to actually query the database first before inserting.

2)As to avoid sessions and such, only other way I can think of would be to save the data to a database and have some user id connected to it.

3)I would recommend a javascript (mvvm framework would be a good choice) solution with ajax postbacks. This would not only stop the user from having full-page postbacks but also enable you to make it feel like a fast and responsive application at the same time. And you can message the user in a more direct manner as well as pointing out where the mistake was and so forth.

Comment: Joakim thanks for that I understand what you mena with the javascript/ajax stuff but I wanted to avoid this incase the user has it switched off.  In terms of inserts yes I can check, but what happens in terms of updates.  Is it worth the overhead of just doing the update again over and over, I am sure there has to be another solution.  Just in case anyone has come across one it would be nice to know as I have read articles saying if you are using Session/Tempdata or any session based store for simple tasks then your achitecture skills need work as there is always an alternative.

Comment: The question you should ask yourself in this case is "What is a simple task?" and what is more taxing on your host? hits on the database? or is it the amount of data actually transferred on a full postback? and also consider if the page does other queries excluding the main action you are focusing on? This is why it has become a more common practice to transfer the user to a page stating that the action has been performed rather than checking immediately due to a number of different reasons.

Also javascript should be an extension and if the user has it disabled the page should degrade to post

Comment: Thanks again.  I understand that and I guess like you said using javascript is not a bad idea for ajax saves etc, and I guess for simple message passing TempData would work as well.  My main reason for wanting to know was also that Sessions have been disabled/not used by my app and I have had only a few issues and have been trying to find work arounds. 1) Being the "thanks/saved" issue as discussed above and the other being the case of saving per user data without sessions which I am attempting to use cache for?  Would Tempdata be disabled if sessions are turned off and load balanced apps?